# command line argument, cant or two variables

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    string s = "all";
    string t = "top";
    for (int i=1; i<argc ; i++)
    {
        cout<< argv[i]<< endl;
        if( argv[2] != s || t)
        {
            cout<<"INVALID MODE"<< endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

> No viable conversion from 'std::__1::string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >') to 'bool'Invalid operands to binary
>
> expression ('bool' and 'std::__1::string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >'))

hello, i am passing command line arguments such as "1 all emptyfile" and "1 top emptyfile", here i want to test if the second argument is not all or top to print out "INVALID MODE". i am having trouble understanding why i cant use the s||t. i get the errors i posted above, is there anyway around this

ive gotten help, thanks to this site, but i have another question, if i have top or all as the second argument, i want it NOT to print out " INVALID MODE". but it seems to be still printout "invalid mode" where in this case all is the second argument, but doesnt seem to print when top is the second argument.

AGAIN thanks so much, another thing i have trouble with, is how to print out "NO PHRASE LENGTH" when no arguments are passed? how does one test that.

also how do i test if the first argument is an integer?, so it if its not an integer and is  negative number print out "Invalid phrase length"

Comment: Don't guess the syntax, read [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If `string.h` brings in `std::string`, your compiler is ancient.

Answer (score 4):

Your expression `argv[2] != s || t` is *grouped* as `(argv[2] != s) || t`, the left hand argument of `||` is then a `bool` type and that's a problem since there is no overloaded `||` operator for `std::string` that takes a `bool`. That explains the cryptic compiler message.

The solution here is to write

```
argv[2] != s && argv[2] != t
```

instead. Note that I've switched `||` for `&&` else the conditional check is always `true` and your program would *always* output `"INVALID MODE"`! Some languages work the way you have it; C++ doesn't.

Comment: I'm kinda surprised `std::string` has no `explicit operator bool`. All the cool languages allow testing strings for truthiness.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Wouldn't that be a bit evil? You could model it on the lines of std::string::c_str, but what if, for example the string had a size of 2 and the first position had a `NUL`?

Comment: I'd consider a sane check to simply be `!empty()` (which is already a thing). And then let the crowds argue about what "empty" should mean philosophically if they so desire.

Comment: @StoryTeller; I'd be in that crowd!

Comment: On the side holding pitchforks or torches? :P

Comment: Probably my duelling pistols.

Answer (score 1):

You have to test like this

```
if( (argv[2] != s) && (argv[2] != t))
```

Some scripting languages allow you to do comparisons like you have done in the question. PERL is one such language.

Comment: ...where I've added excess parentheses for clarity / I'm a quiche eater / I'm a girl / I can't be bothered to commit the operator precedence table to memory.

Comment: Or dietary habits either? It's a nice answer though. +1 for good feelings.

Comment: Thanks. Upped your answer too.

Comment: thank you, that seems to clear the error, but i have another question, if i have top or all as the second argument, i want it NOT to print out " INVALID MODE". but it seems to be still printout "invalid mode" where in this case all is the second argument.

Comment: @user10388866: You need `&&` rather than `||`

Comment: Yes, I chose PERL over Python years back: an action similar to my father when he purchased a Betamax video player.

Comment: @P.W. My favourite Birman cat at home (and I have four) is called Bathsheba. Named after Bathsheba Everdene in "Far from the Madding Crowd", or King David's better half.

Comment: Yeah, David's 8th wife. Can't fault him though. He was a king after all.